# How to display Hindi font in android application with utf-8 ?

Tags: android, json, utf-8

I have developed an application that have display in text view hindi and other indian languages functionality and its getting data from php mysql server using json url but problem is when I got the data English display perfect but when I get data in hindi and other languages its showing like this `??????  ????? ???? ???? ?????`.

What is fault behind and which side php side or android side ?

Main activity code :

```
 public class JSONUseActivity extends Activity {

        String returnString;  
        private TextView about;
        private ImageView image;
        String image_url;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
         .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() 
         .penaltyLog().build());
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_jsonuse);

           about=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
           Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(JSONUseActivity.this.getAssets(),"Shruti.ttf");
           about.setTypeface(tf);
           image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
           url_through_image.ImageLoader imgloader=new url_through_image.ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
           ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

           int loader = R.drawable.loader;
          postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("temple_id",
          "2"));
              String response = null;

              try {
                  response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
                          "url",  // in case of a remote server
           postParameters);


                  String result = response.toString();  


             try{
                     returnString = "";
               JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                     for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
                     {
                             JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                             returnString=json_data.getString("about_text");
                             image_url="url";

                     }
             }
             catch(JSONException e){
                     Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
             }

             try{
              about.setText(returnString);
              imgloader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader,image);
             }
             catch(Exception e){
              Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;          
             }   
        }
              catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     
        }
             }         

        }



json parser is here..

     private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {

  if (mHttpClient == null) {
   mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

   final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
   HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
   HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
   ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
  }

  return mHttpClient;
 }
    public static String executeHttpPost(String url,ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader in = null;

      try {

       HttpClient client = getHttpClient();

       HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

       UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(

         postParameters,"UTF-8");

       request.setEntity(formEntity);

       HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

       in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()

         .getContent() ,"UTF-8"));



       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");

       String line = "";

       String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

       while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

        sb.append(line + NL);

       }

       in.close();


       String result = sb.toString();

       return result;

      } finally {

   if (in != null) {

    try {

     in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

     Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString()); 

     e.printStackTrace();

    }

   }

  }

 }

 public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {

  BufferedReader in = null;

  try {

   HttpClient client = getHttpClient();

   HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

   request.setURI(new URI(url));

   HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()

     .getContent(),"UTF-8"));


   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");

   String line = "";

   String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

   while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

    sb.append(line + NL);

   }

   in.close();


   String result = sb.toString();

   return result;

  } finally {

   if (in != null) {

    try {

     in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

     Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString()); 

     e.printStackTrace();

    }

   }
  }
```

> [image]

Comment: textview.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Hindi.ttf")); try this..

Comment: i already use this look my code...

Comment: ok,i see,u try to change shruti.ttf in to Hindi.ttf

Comment: shruti,ttf is for hindi and gujarati font, so i dont think this is issue

Comment: yes... Shruti.ttf is hindi font file....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47916/discussion-between-pranav-lathigara-and-rajshree)

Comment: if you have found solution for your problem, please post it. i am facing same problem for gujarati text in my app

Comment: i got simple solution...if u r fetching gujarati data from server then just store in form of UTF-8 and then parse it in your application